# Citing in the bibliography of a separate document

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, multiple-files

I'm trying to cite references in a supplementary information file from the bibliography (using bibtex) of a main text file. Can I do this so as to use the same numbering is an the main text and keeping them as separate documents (just one bib for the main text)?

I have `xr` working fine between the two for figure panel cross-referencing, but this doesn't seem to work for citations (`xcite` seems to have now been replaced by `xr`, but I'm not sure it could this anyway).

Comment: If you use xelatex, see this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/118#issuecomment-624770794). Otherwise, please provide more info.

Comment: I'm using the pdflatex engine in overleaf. I'm not so concerned about the hyperlinks for now. I just want the citations to appear in the supplementary info, but pointing to the main text bib.